# Create a Wordpress post using curl comand from Linux console?

Tags: posts, curl

Is it possible to create a Wordpress page or post with a curl command from Linux console?

I tried using the available REST API, but for some reason can't figure it out. If you could give me an example I will be very happy.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code that you tried with REST?

Comment: Also what kind of authentication did you use?

Comment: Is the [WP-CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/create/) an option?

Comment: Hello and thanks for the comments.
No, wp-cli is not an option for now.

I tried this so far `curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"Title","content":"Content","type":"page"}' http://site-domain.com/wp-json.php/posts -u user:pwd`

Comment: I figured it out. What I had to do is to enable pretty permalinks (because my Wordpress Docker container didnt have it enabled) and rest API started working.

Comment: Please post your own solving comment as an answer and accept it, for future readers to see what the issue was.